# Can't use any USB devices / storage problems

Tags: usb, storage

My laptop (Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 20.04) doesn't show my USB devices in the files as it did before, not among other locations, not in the GParted tool or anywhere else. USB devices *do* show up in the terminal with their correct name, but that's the only place where I find them. It doesn't matter what USB device (I tested several) or which port. In Windows all the devices show up just as usual.

Also my laptop always tells me that the storage is full, although that's practically impossible. I have 1 TB storage and a very big partition for my stuff that does by far not look like full, and even if I would have mistaken if it's the right partition - there doesn't show up just any partition with little space.

I don't know how these two things could have something to do with each other, but both problems showed up at the same time, although I didn't have these problems before.

I found out that the problem is about the device marked in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I also got problems with opening files and programs now. I just don't know what of the stuff on the mentioned device could be deleted and what not, or if there is a way to get more storage to the device.

I don't know how to do the `df` output into better formatting, so I'll just add a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot df output]

Results of `df -m | grep -v loop` :

```
Filesystem     1M-blocks    Used Available  Use% Mounted o
udev                7818       0      7818    0% /dev
tmpfs               1571       3      1569    1% /run 
/dev/nvme0n1p5    119739   65942     47673   59% / 
tmpfs               7852      56      7797    1% /dev/shm 
tmpfs                  5       1         5    1% /run/lock 
tmpfs               7852       0      7852    0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
/dev/nvme0n1p1        96      77        20   80% /boot/efi 
tmpfs               1571       1      1571    1% /run/user/1000
```

There also additional problems after some time now. It's taking several tries to displace or delete files now and opening and using applications needs several tries or doesn't work properly.

Comment: Disk space? Is there a full partition on your  disk? `df -m | grep -v loop`. Look at how your system detects its hardware with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`

Comment: @waltinator When I put in `df -m | grep -v loop` I get `Dateisystem 1M-Blöcke Benutzt Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev                7818       0      7818    0% /dev
tmpfs               1571       3      1569    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5    119739   65942     47673   59% /
tmpfs               7852      56      7797    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5       1         5    1% /run/lock
tmpfs               7852       0      7852    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1        96      77        20   80% /boot/efi
tmpfs               1571       1      1571    1% /run/user/1000`

Comment: Okay, I found out, which one got too few space. It's this one (added a photo to the question - it's the red marked one). Is there a way to add space to it? `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` didn't work. How to find out what data could be deleted and what data not?

Comment: The photo points to what seems to be removable storage (e.g., a USB drive). I would take that out, ensure that your main partitions are not the problem (as @waltinator suggested), and then start `tail -f /var/log/syslog` as I would insert the USB drive. The log is going to show you what it is seeing and what it is doing with it. (And, please move the `df` output to your question with proper formatting because it is unusable as it is.)

Comment: @ATony No, it's not a USB drive, I don't know where it belongs to, but it's always been listed there since I installed ubuntu and I never cared about it. Always thought it's something internal.

Comment: I don't understand the language so it is even harder to glean any tips from the screenshot. Could it be your efi partition? Although, if that is the case, I can't understand why it would interfere with connecting USBs. Try inspecting the USB connection as I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: please add `sudo lsblk -f` so we see the filesystem. And `getfacl /media/$USER`